Why am I getting extremely slow read/write speed on an external SSD?
I've been using a Crucial X10 Pro external SSD (4tb) for a little while now, and despite it being advertised as having read and write speed of around 2000 MB/s, I cannot get it to go faster than a measly 40 MB/s. Here are the winsat results for this drive as well as my internal SSD for comparison:
External:
Windows System Assessment Tool
> Running: Feature Enumeration ''
> Run Time 00:00:00.00
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive f -ran -read'
> Run Time 00:00:23.59
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive f -seq -read'
> Run Time 00:00:09.45
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive f -seq -write'
> Run Time 00:00:14.55
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive f -flush -seq'
> Run Time 00:00:02.67
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive f -flush -ran'
> Run Time 00:00:02.88
> Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
> Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
> Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       26.24 MB/s          6.1
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   39.85 MB/s          4.9
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  40.18 MB/s          5.0
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     1.200 ms          7.5
> Latency: 95th Percentile                     1.867 ms          7.8
> Latency: Maximum                             51.726 ms          7.9
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         1.225 ms          8.2

Internal:
Windows System Assessment Tool
> Running: Feature Enumeration ''
> Run Time 00:00:00.00
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -ran -read'
> Run Time 00:03:36.98
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -read'
> Run Time 00:00:23.83
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -write'
> Run Time 00:00:27.08
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -seq'
> Run Time 00:00:02.28
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -ran'
> Run Time 00:00:03.22
> Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
> Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
> Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       745.54 MB/s          8.5
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   2927.99 MB/s          9.2
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  2499.27 MB/s          9.1
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     0.063 ms          8.9
> Latency: 95th Percentile                     0.228 ms          8.8
> Latency: Maximum                             13.662 ms          7.9
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         0.075 ms          8.9

I'm currently using a USB 3.0 port but I got similar results when connecting to a 2.0 port as well. The drive is currently formatted as exFAT if that helps.

Are you using usb a or usb c?

I do not know how the "Windows System Assessment Tool" works, but keep in mind that USB still carries a significant amount of overhead when doing many IOps. So if its doing alot of small operations, this will likely be the result. Have you tried moving large files to/from the drive to test it ? Also, USB2.0 only has 480mbit throughput + even more overhead, so 40MB/sec is exactly what you would expect to see.

One possible explanation is you are using a USB-C to USB-A cable that only supports data transfer up to 480 Mb/s. For example, this cable only has a twisted pair of wires to support legacy USB 2.0 speeds of up to 480 Mb/s. Below is a diagram of the cable. (For a better view, either click on the image, open the image in a new window or click on the link.)

The proper cable should have to two addition twisted pairs of wires to support data transfer speeds of 5 Gb/s. For example, this cable has a twisted pair of wires to support legacy USB 2.0 speeds of up to 480 Mb/s and two additional twisted pairs of wires to support USB 3.0 speeds of up to 5 Gb/s. Below is a diagram of the cable. (For a better view, either click on the image, open the image in a new window or click on the link.)


Not sure if this is from the exact model your using, but it probably still applies if you are using a USB-A cable instead of a USB-C.


Best speeds available with included USB Type-C to C cable on USB 3.2 Gen2 supported devices. Use USB Type-A adapter for older devices. USB 3.2 Gen2 2x2 full performance can only be achieved on USB-C host
devices.


